# Counting Rows in column of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop over each staff members roster and automate slotting them into a free session. Part of this is counting rows in column of current cell (Session)

The **Roster** data looks like
[image]

The **sessions** data looks like

[image]

The code so far is :

```
Sub ScheduleSession()
Dim Roster As Worksheet
Dim Sessions As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim row As Range
Dim Session As Range

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Roster")
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
For x = LastRow To 8 Step -1

    If IsEmpty((.Range("B" & x))) Then
        ' Look for a session
        Debug.Print ("Looking For a Session for " & (.Range("A" & x)))
                For Each Session In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sessions").Range("A1:E1").Cells
                    Debug.Print (Session)
                    ' Check session is not full (3 per session) else next session
                    SessionCount = Cells(Rows.Count, Session.Columns.Count).End(xlUp).row
                    If (SessionCount > 4) Then
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        ' Loop over cells in employee roster to see if they are working on given day and time.
                        ' If so roster them by recording session against employee (on ROSTER col B) and employee against session in appropriate col on SESSIONS
                    End If
                Next

    Else
        ' Employee already scheduled
        Debug.Print ("This employee " & (.Range("A" & x)) & " already has a session")
    End If

Next x
End With
```

Can I please get help with counting the rows in the For Each Session loop line which current is a Run-time Error 91 - Object Variable with Block Variable Not Set.

This question has been answered many times, but the other answers I see don't show how to apply it to a range like Session.

If anyone is feeling generous some guidance on going to the employee roster from each session to check if they are working and available to be scheduled would be great.

**UPDATE** Sorry Sessions is Session

```
SessionCount = Cells(Rows.Count, Session.Columns.Count).End(xlUp).row
```

Since I need the number of rows in the current session in the For Each Session loop.

Comment: What happens when you use "Sessions.Cells(Rows.Count,Sessions.Columns.Count).End(xlup).row"? That is where you get the error, right?

Comment: Why use session.rows.count and session.columns.count? Since you loop over each cell in the range, the number of rows and columns will always be 1, so you will always get Cells(1,1).End(xlup).row

Comment: @AlexdeJong no expert here, but I think it gives you the number of the column, and row within the sheet, not within the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SessionCount = Cells(Rows.Count, Session.Columns.Count).End(xlUp).row
```

Here `Session` is a single cell, so you're always looking at the first column...

```
SessionCount = Cells(Rows.Count, Session.Column).End(xlUp).row
```

...is probably what you want

Comment: Thanks. Any input on the other part of the loop to check session time against roster?

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't set the Variable `Sessions` yet. Somewhere after the `Dim Sessions As Worksheet`, you need to add `Set Sessions = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sessions")`